# SSH into my Mac OS Lion - slight dilemma

Tags: ssh, ping

I'm trying to enable my Mac Lion (which has a username `xyz`) for ssh. I've done these steps:

- System Preferences -> Sharing -> Enable Remote Login for all Users
- System Preferences -> Network -> Wireless -> Advanced -> TCP/IP and then I selected "Using DHCP with manual address" and then typed in 192.168.1.15 (my router is 192.168.1.1)
- Went into my Router settings (I have a Netgear router), and added a custom service port forwarding named "SSH" on port 22, and indicated the IP as 192.168.1.15

Then I went to whatismyip.com and checked my ip address, which came back as XX.XX.XXX.XX

Then I went to my other computer and in the terminal I typed

```
ssh xyz@XX.XX.XXX.XX
```

and then it stalled for a few minutes and then said

```
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XXX.XX port 22: Operation timed out
```

Note that if in the terminal I do a

```
ping -p 22 XX.XX.XXX.XX
```

it seems to work:

```
64 bytes from 68.49.223.82: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.522 ms
64 bytes from 68.49.223.82: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.681 ms
64 bytes from 68.49.223.82: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.727 ms
64 bytes from 68.49.223.82: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.124 ms
etc.
```

. Any ideas? How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Your router thinks the machines on the LAN want to talk to *it*, so it is consuming (and subsequently dropping) the packets. Either connect from a machine outside the network, or use the internal IP address instead.

Comment: doesn't work from outside the network either...any ideas?